# How to set the priority of host headers in IIS 6?

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, hosting, iis-6, host-headers

On my IIS 6 Server, I have two sites:

```
Site 1: abc.example.com //Should respond only to header value abc.example.com
Site 2: 198.51.100.1 //Should respond if no host header matches
```

However it seems that site 2 always responds. I have created site 2 after sit one. How can I make Site 1 have priority?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the only entry in the Advanced Web Site Identification screen for **Site 1** is exactly as follows:

```
IP Address: 198.51.100.1
TCP port: 80
Host header value: abc.example.com
```

The default entry (and any other entries) should be removed.

For **Site 2**, make sure that the default entry in the Advanced Web Site Identification screen is the only entry.

For both sites, the IP Address should be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Site 1 should respond in your scenario. I would double-check the entries. Are you sure you are binding both to the same IP? (not All IP's or whatever) Also you could try to stop and restart IIS.